# Connect a external SSH Server from blocked SSH Tunnel network

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, firewall

I need connect to SSH Server in my work office from a academic network, but in all tries occurred a "Timeout error". In my home and in other places the access work fine to connect (SSH Server working fine!).

I tried to access public SSH Server in port 22 but TimeOut occurred again.

This academic network have not proxy, i can use my notebook to access all things on internet. Some tries:

```
ssh username@targetip -p port

ssh -R remoteIP:remoteport:localIP:localport hostname

ssh -C2qTnN -D 9090 username@targetip -p port
```

But nothing!

Some ideas? I will try OpenVPN, but i want not configure and use VPN all time.

Thanks

Comment: The provider of your acedemic network does not permit outgoing connections on port 22.  Ask them to open it?

Answer (score 0):

> Ask [the provider] to open [port 22]

I don't think that's going to happen for security reasons. Run `sshd` on your server listening on port 443 and use `proxytunnel` or `nc` as `ProxyCommand` in your `~/.ssh/config` to cross the outgoing http-proxy of your academic network.